# How can i pass two variable in one Ant target by spliting commas

Tags: ant

I have one `deploy.path1=A,B,C,D,E` and `deploy.path2=1,2,3,4` and I want to use A and 1 in one target Deploy like below eg at one time means both should be available at same time like A,1 then next time B,2 and so on...

```
<target name"deploy">
<echo message="${A}"/>
<echo message="${1}"/>
</target>
```

How can i do this?

Currently I'm using

```
<foreach list="${deploy.loc2}" param="deploy_javapass" target="copy_patch_javapass" delimiter="," inheritall="true" inheritrefs="true" 
    parallel="false" trim="true"/>
```

task but in this way we can pass only one parameter at one time.

Answer (score 1):

I rarely use the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) tasks. If you need complex logic, I'd suggest embedding a proper scripting language, for example the [groovy task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task).

The following example invokes the "deploy" task in the manner you've described:

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <property name="deploy.path1" value="A,B,C,D,E"/>
    <property name="deploy.path2" value="1,2,3,4,5"/>

    <target name="run">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="/path/to/groovy/jar/groovy-all-1.8.5.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>

        <groovy>
        def values1 = properties."deploy.path1".split(",")
        def values2 = properties."deploy.path2".split(",")

        values1.eachWithIndex { value1, i ->
            properties.val1 = value1
            properties.val2 = values2[i]

            ant.project.executeTarget('deploy')
        }
        </groovy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <echo message="path1 = ${val1}"/>
        <echo message="path2 = ${val2}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

---

## Enhanced example using ivy to managed 3rd party jars

For new ANT installations, I added an extra target to the build file:

```
$ ant install-ivy
```

This will setup ivy by downloading the ivy task jar.

Using ivy for one ANT task is over-kill. However it more than pays off when you use it to manage your various classpaths.

Maven central has a vast range of open source libraries available for download:

http://search.maven.org/

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="run" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <property name="deploy.path1" value="A,B,C,D,E"/>
    <property name="deploy.path2" value="1,2,3,4,5"/>

    <target name="install-ivy">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.2.0/ivy-2.2.0.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path" conf="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="init">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <groovy>
        def values1 = properties."deploy.path1".split(",")
        def values2 = properties."deploy.path2".split(",")

        values1.eachWithIndex { value1, i ->
            properties.val1 = value1
            properties.val2 = values2[i]

            ant.project.executeTarget('deploy')
        }
        </groovy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy">
        <echo message="path1 = ${val1}"/>
        <echo message="path2 = ${val2}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml:

ivy file listing the build's dependencies:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="myorg" module="mymodule" />
    <configurations>
        <conf name="build" description="Build dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="1.8.5" conf="build->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:resolve

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\pkumar\Desktop\PKUMAR\XML\ivy.xml:7: syntax errors in ivy file: java.text.ParseException: [xml parsing: ivy.xml:1:74: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declarati
on of element 'project'. in file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/pkumar/Desktop/PKUMAR/XML/ivy.xml
, unknown tag project in file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/pkumar/Desktop/PKUMAR/XML/ivy.xml
, unknown tag echo in file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/pkumar/Desktop/PKUMAR/XML/ivy.xml
, unknown tag echo in file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/pkumar/Desktop/PKUMAR/XML/ivy.xml
]

Comment: Apologies for complicating the example by using ivy :-)  I've revised the answer, hopefully you should be able to get it working now.