# Ant property with multiple values each on separate line

Tags: ant

I have a property that has to contain long list of strings and to improve readability I would like to define each value (that are quite long) in separate line, something like:

```
<property name="items" separator=",">
   <item>A</item>
   <item>B</item>
</property>
```

as equivalent to

```
<property name="items" value="A,B" />
```

Or something similar to `<path>` + `<pathconvert>` but not expanding paths.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out there are string resources and a generic resource container:

```
<resources id="items">
  <string>A</string>
  <string>B</string>
</resources>
<pathconvert property="items" refid="items" pathsep="," />
```

Comment: This is great, thanks, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it?

Comment: Actually it's as simple as it looks! :)

Just use it afterwards like:

```<runJunit classname="${items}" />```

Answer (score 0):

Not supported by standard ANT.

There is a popular [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) plugin that has a "foreach" task which acts upon comma separated properties, but I prefer to embed a proper programming language. [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) stands out due it's excellent Java and ANT integration.

Examples of list handling:

- [Change values of list in ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259400/change-values-of-list-in-ant/17260745#17260745)
- [How can i pass two variable in one Ant target by spliting commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131091/how-can-i-pass-two-variable-in-one-ant-target-by-spliting-commas/9131745#9131745)

Comment: Actually, I've found a way to do it and it was rather straightforward. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use:

```
<property file='lists.properties'/>
```

Then create a separate file named lists.properties:

```
#sample properties, you can use \ for line continuation
example=A,\
B,\
C
```

Then back in the build.xml you can use 'example' property:

```
${example}
```

You can have multiple properties defined in the lists.properties.

Note : this does NOT work for depends="..." lists.  For that I recommend using multiple antcall's in the task instead of a long depends list.

Thanks,